# Не срабатывает background-size: cover

Tags: html

Почему не срабатывает background-size: cover? Попробовал создать тестовую страницу, удалив всё лишнее, и там тоже самое.

Вот текст HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleindex_tst.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

А вот CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url("img/fav.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

При таком коде изображение растягивается только по ширине. Красный цвет фона я задал, чтобы убедиться, что цвет при этом заливает всю и ширину и высоту, и это действительно так. Что я сделал неправильно? Попытки изменить размер на 100% не изменили ситуацию. Если убрать no-repeat, начинается мозайка, которая мне не нужна

Comment: высоту укажите ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высоту не забывайте указывать. И заглядывайте в панель разработчика в браузере. Много вопросов отпадать будет :)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```